# Mapbox JSON style upload error: "Sprite does not exist or is private"

Tags: json, download, upload, styles, transfer

Trying to transfer a style between 2 accounts by downloading the JSON styles from one studio style and then uploading it to a second account.

When transferring a private map style from account 1 to account 2, during the upload process to account 2, I get "Sprite does not exist or is private" the upload fails. I don't want to make the styles public, just need to transfer the styles from my dev account to the client's production site. The sprites that I am using are all specified in my JS so the sprite that is referenced in the style is not important anyway. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sprite is not important, then you can open the `style.json` file and update

```
"sprite": "<private-sprite>",
```

to

```
"sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/bright-v8",
```

This would at least pass the upload validation, but like I said, it would not be the same if the correct sprites are necessary.

[Docs on Mapbox Sprite](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sprite)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set to public the map for a couple of seconds in the original account while you upload the style.json on the second account once the upload is complete you can set back to private the original map

https://blog.mapbox.com/introducing-private-maps-and-data-encryption-129488b9f434